# How do we justify this substitution within an identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let me clarify that $x$ and $k$ are both real numbers in this question, just so that I do not have to write $\in \mathbb{R}$ like a million times.
If we take some identity, like $$\forall x, \space  (x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1\space\space(1),$$ it is allowed to write $$x=k+1\space\space(2)$$ for some $k$. We can then substitute this into the identity to make  $$\forall   k,   (k+2)^2 = (k+1)^2 + 2(k+1) + 1 \space\space(3).$$ Now going back to our substitution, the proper way to write it would have been $\forall x \exists k$ such that $x = k+1$, how do we justify that $(3)$ holds for $\forall k$, if we only know the identity and $(2)$? I understand that for each $x$ we have a unique $k$ but cannot quite justify how that means $(3)$ holds for all $k$, if the identity initially held for all $x$.

Comment: Are you using this in an natural or mathematical induction context?  That is the most common place I see the substitution,  x= k+1.  In natural induction, we can *not* assume $\forall x$.  The point of induction proofs is to prove for all natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $\forall x\exists k,$ write
$$\forall k\exists x\quad x=k+1\tag{4}$$
By the [substitution axiom for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms),
$$(P(x)\text{ and }x=k+1)\implies P(k+1).$$
Therefore,
$$((1)\text{ and }(4))\implies(3).$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement after, "clearly"? I will mark your answer as the accepted solution, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "Substitution for formulas. For any variables x and y and any formula φ(x), if φ' is obtained by replacing any number of free occurrences of x in φ with y, such that these remain free occurrences of y", I cannot find the exact phrase you hyperlinked, thanks.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. And then, inside   $$x=y→ (φ → φ'),$$  you may replace every free occurrence of the variable $y$ with a term, like $k+1.$

Comment: Can the downvoter of today (more than 3 months later) please explain how this answer could be improved?